# jquery clone and removebycontent ... is not a function?

Tags: jquery, clone

i like to clone a table and remove the word EUR from each cell. I tried with .removeByContent but got the error "is not a function".

This is my code:

```
var cln = $('#tableid').clone();
cln.find('.noExl').remove();
cln.removeByContent('EUR');
```

And this is the table:

```
<table id="tableid"><tr><td>Bacon</td><td>140 EUR</td></tr><tr><td>Ham</td><td>70 EUR</td></tr></table>
```

How can i remove a String in the cloned element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *loop* through tds and then use `replace("EUR", "")` to replace `EUR` text from tds .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var cln = $('#tableid').clone();
//find tds in cloned htmls
cln.find("td").each(function() {
  //replace text with ""
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace("EUR", "").trim())
})

$(cln).appendTo($("#new_ids"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Bacon</td>
    <td>140 EUR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ham</td>
    <td>70 EUR</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="new_ids"></div>
```